# Flex Conditional Validation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm trying to do validation on three fields in an mxml file. Two of them are required, one isn't. The zip code field I only want to be validated if something is entered into it. If it's blank, then I want to allow the 'submit' button to be enabled, as long as the other two required fields are correctly set. Code:

```
<mx:EmailValidator id="emailValidator" 
                       property="text" source="{ownerName}"
                       valid="emailValidator_validHandler(event)"
                       invalid="emailValidator_validHandler(event)"/>
    <mx:ZipCodeValidator id="zipCodeValidator"
                         property="text" source="{zip}"
                         required="false"
                         valid="zipCodeValidator_validHandler(event)"
                         invalid="zipCodeValidator_validHandler(event)"/>

    <mx:Validator id="roomNameValidator" 
                  property="text" source="{roomName}"
                  valid="roomNameValidator_validHandler(event)"
                  invalid="roomNameValidator_validHandler(event)"/>
        [Bindable]
        private var isRoomNameValid:Boolean;
        [Bindable]
        private var isOwnerValid:Boolean;
        [Bindable]
        private var isZipValid:Boolean;

        protected function emailValidator_validHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
        {
            isOwnerValid = (event.type==ValidationResultEvent.VALID);
        }

        protected function zipCodeValidator_validHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
        {
            isZipValid = (event.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID);
        }
        protected function roomNameValidator_validHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
        {
            isRoomNameValid = (event.type==ValidationResultEvent.VALID);
        }
```

I then tried to set the enabled property of the submit button:

```
 enabled = "{isOwnerValid &amp;&amp; isRoomNameValid &amp;&amp zip.text.length>0?isZipValid:true}"
```

But it doesn't work. I can still submit bad data in the zip field, even though the zip code field shows the red border.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but you may want to seriously consider using some type of MVC.  All of that logic in your enabled function has a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My previous suggestion might have resulted in an infinite loop :-)

I would suggest using the change method of the text boxes to perform validation as follows:

```
protected function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    submitButton.enabled = Validator.validateAll(validators.source);
}

<mx:ArrayCollection id="validators">
    <mx:EmailValidator id="emailValidator"
                   property="text" source="{ownerName}" />        
    <mx:ZipCodeValidator id="zipCodeValidator"
                   property="text" source="{zip}"
                   required="false" />
    <mx:Validator id="roomNameValidator" 
                   property="text" source="{roomName}" />
</mx:ArrayCollection>

<mx:Label text="Owner Name:" />
<mx:TextInput id="ownerName" change="changeHandler(event)" />
<mx:Label text="Zip Code:" />
<mx:TextInput id="zip" change="changeHandler(event)" />
<mx:Label text="Room Name:" />
<mx:TextInput id="roomName" change="changeHandler(event)" />
<mx:Button id="submitButton" label="Submit" enabled="false" />
```

Comment: Hi Trish. Thanks for the answer. I've tried the code and it still lets me submit bad data even though the red outline appears around the zip code box.

Answer (score 0):

First, as the Zip code is not mandatory, you should initialize it to `true` :

**[Bindable] var isZipValid:Boolean = true;**

---

Now here's a solution:

```
protected function zipCodeValidator_validHandler(event:ValidationResultEvent):void
{
    isZipValid = (zip.text.length == 0) || (event.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID);
}
```

and then in your submit button

```
enabled = "{isOwnerValid && isRoomNameValid && isZipValid}"
```

---

An alternative solution would be: enabling As the validator itself only when zip Zip code is not emptymandatory, you should initialize it to true :

```
<mx:ZipCodeValidator id="zipCodeValidator"
                 property="text" source="{zip}"
                 required="false"
                 valid="zipCodeValidator_validHandler(event)"
                 invalid="zipCodeValidator_validHandler(event)"
                 enabled="{zip.text.length > 0}"/>
```

[Bindable] var isZipValid:Boolean = true;

Comment: Tried this code -- it lets me submit an unacceptable zip code even though the error message shows. It looks like I'll have to write a custom class, which I'll post here if successful.